# SwiftUI: button on the bottom get stretched when ignoreSsafeArea on background picture

Tags: swift, swiftui

The button on the problem get's stretched when I add a picture as the background and I add the `.ignoreSafeArea` Modifier.

The only solution I found so far is add a `Spacer().frame(height: 1)` after the button. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Test") {
                               //Action
                                }.font(.system(size: 50))
                                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                    .background(Color.red)

                // when i add this spacer to the bottom i have an space between the button and the bottom of the preview phone if not the button gets stretched to the bottom of the phone

                Spacer().frame(height: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about padding and background.

You can add `.padding(.bottom)` under `.background(Color.red)`

```
Button("Test") {
      //Action
}
.font(.system(size: 50))
.fontWeight(.heavy)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.padding(.horizontal)
.background(Color.red)
.padding(.bottom)
```